# Обработка возврата на шаг назад между двумя активити

Tags: android

Подскажите пожалуйста, как можно избежать следующей ошибки: При нажатии на стандартную клавишу "Back" возврата на шаг назад эмулятора или смартфона приложение вылетает.
Лог пишет:

java.lang.NullPointerException

В коде подчёркивает вот эту строку - **if (myWebView.canGoBack() == true) {**

```
public class FourActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

WebView myWebView;
public static String ONE = "ONE";
final String LOG_TAG = "myLogs";

@SuppressLint("SetJavaScriptEnabled")
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_third);

    // Получаем данные от деятельности ThirdActivity
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    int one = intent.getIntExtra(ONE, R.raw.money);

    WebView myWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);

    WebSettings settings = myWebView.getSettings();
    settings.setDefaultTextEncodingName("utf-8");
    myWebView.getSettings().setLayoutAlgorithm(
            WebSettings.LayoutAlgorithm.SINGLE_COLUMN);
    myWebView.setBackgroundColor(0x00000000);
    myWebView.setLayerType(WebView.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null);
    myWebView.getSettings().setCacheMode(
            WebSettings.LOAD_CACHE_ELSE_NETWORK);
    myWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    myWebView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
    myWebView.getSettings().setSupportZoom(true);
    myWebView.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);

    myWebView(getResources().getString(one));

    // получаем контекст
    Context context = getBaseContext();
    String text_one = readRawTextFile(context, one);

    // Получаем доступ к WebView и загружаем туда HTML страницу
    String sum_one = "<!Doctype html><html><head><meta charset=utf-8></head><body>"
            + text_one + "</body></html>";

    myWebView
            .loadDataWithBaseURL(null, sum_one, "text/html", "utf-8", null);

}

private void myWebView(String string) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
}

// читаем текст из raw
public static String readRawTextFile(Context ctx, int resId) {
    InputStream inputStream = ctx.getResources().openRawResource(resId);

    InputStreamReader inputreader = new InputStreamReader(inputStream);
    BufferedReader buffreader = new BufferedReader(inputreader);
    String line = null;
    StringBuilder text = new StringBuilder();

    try {
        while ((line = buffreader.readLine()) != null) {
            text.append(line);
            text.append("<!Doctype html><html><head><meta charset=utf-8></head><body>"
                    + "</body></html>");
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        return line;
    }
    return text.toString();
}

// обработка возврата на шаг назад
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if (event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
        switch (keyCode) {
        case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK:
            if (myWebView.canGoBack() == true) {
                myWebView.goBack();
            } else {
                finish();
            }
            return true;
        }

    }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}

public void onClick(View v) {
    finish();
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // добавляем элементы в акшион бар
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.third, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    // Проверяем ориентацию экрана
    if (newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT) {

    } else if (newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE) {

    }
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {

    case R.id.item_1: {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, FirstActivity.class);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP
                | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
        setResult(RESULT_OK, intent);
        startActivity(intent);
        return false;
    }
    default:
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);

    }

}

public WebView getMyWebView() {
    return myWebView;
}

public void setMyWebView(WebView myWebView) {
    this.myWebView = myWebView;
}

public String getLOG_TAG() {
    return LOG_TAG;
}

public static String getONE() {
    return ONE;
}

public static void setONE(String oNE) {
    ONE = oNE;
}
```

Comment: наверно потому, что myWebView = null. Либо добавьте проверку на это, либо посмотрите код и подумайте, почему myWebView может быть null.

Comment: WebView myWebView;

И какое значение ему присвоить?

Comment: как вам уже писали, у вас где-то об**null**яется myWebView.    
Если приведете больше кода, то вам возможно смогут помочь...

Comment: Привёл весь!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

замените

```
WebView myWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);
```

на

```
myWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);
```

Локальная переменная у вас имеет то же имя что и переменная класса.

Comment: Большое спасибо! Как всегда всё оказалось не так страшно.

Answer (score 0):

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    if (webview.canGoBack()) {
        webview.goBack();
    } else {
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}
```

Comment: Не работает. Та же картина.

Comment: значит myWebView null